# Align the globes and lights elements to be on the tree no mater the width of the window

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-position

Having the following code snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: #9fd8ee;
}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.triangle-one {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -69px;
}

.triangle-two {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.triangle-three {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 200px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -80px;
}

.triangle-four {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -120px;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: maroon;
}

.globe {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}

.glpos-1 {
  background: red;
  top: 175px;
  left: 630px;
}

.glpos-2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 225px;
  left: 655px;
}

.glpos-3 {
  background: yellow;
  top: 315px;
  left: 610px;
}

.glpos-4 {
  background: orange;
  top: 375px;
  left: 680px;
}

.glpos-5 {
  background: cyan;
  top: 425px;
  left: 640px;
}

.glpos-6 {
  background: red;
  top: 535px;
  left: 700px;
}

.glpos-7 {
  background: blue;
  top: 510px;
  left: 590px;
}

.light {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  animation: example 1s infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

.lipos-1 {
  top: 260px;
  left: 620px;
}

.lipos-2 {
  top: 300px;
  left: 710px;
}

.lipos-3 {
  top: 410px;
  left: 590px;
}

.lipos-4 {
  top: 510px;
  left: 730px;
}

.lipos-5 {
  top: 160px;
  left: 666px;
}

.lipos-6 {
  top: 417px;
  left: 700px;
}

.lipos-7 {
  top: 480px;
  left: 610px;
}

@keyframes example {
  50% {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #ccc, -2px 1px 10px #ccc, 0 -1px 10px #ccc;
  }
}

.star {
  margin: 50px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid yellow;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(35deg) scale(0.75);
}
.star:before {
  border-bottom: 80px solid yellow;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
}
.star:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: yellow;
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid yellow;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-70deg);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Christmas tree</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tree">
      <div class="star"></div>
      <div class="triangle-one"></div>
      <div class="triangle-two"></div>
      <div class="triangle-three"></div>
      <div class="triangle-four"></div>
      <div class="rectangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="globe glpos-1"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-2"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-3"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-4"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-5"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-6"></div>
    <div class="globe glpos-7"></div>

    <div class="light lipos-1"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-2"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-3"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-4"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-5"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-6"></div>
    <div class="light lipos-7"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the Dev tools is opened, the width of the window is around 1200px and in that case all the globes and lights are situated on the tree.

How can they be changed in order to be on the tree no mater the width of the window?

Comment: use percentage value for left

Answer (score 0):

Why not a different idea with less of code and responsive. I picked the clip-path of the star from here: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

```css
.tree {
  max-width:300px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  /* the bottom of the tree */
  border-bottom:50px solid transparent;
  background:linear-gradient(maroon 0 0) bottom/20% 50px no-repeat border-box; 
}
.tree  div {
  padding-top:200%; /* keep it responsive at the same ratio */
}
.tree::before { /* the star */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;    
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  background:yellow;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
}
.tree > div::before,
.tree > div::after{  /* the main part of the tree */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  --g:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,rgb(20, 97, 27) 50%) no-repeat;
  background:
    var(--g) -120% calc(0*100%/3),
    var(--g) -70%  calc(1*100%/3),
    var(--g) -30%  calc(2*100%/3),
    var(--g) 0     calc(3*100%/3);
  background-size:200% calc(100%/4 + 17%); /* update the 17% to control the shape */
  background-origin: content-box;
} 
.tree > div::after {
  transform-origin:right;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
.tree::after { /* the non animated globes */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
      /*                          color            position:  X   Y*/
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,red    98%,transparent ) 50% 30%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,blue   98%,transparent ) 60% 70%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,pink   98%,transparent ) 40% 50%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,purple 98%,transparent ) 30% 90%;
  background-size:8% 4%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
i {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4%;
  height: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  animation: ex 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes ex {
 50% {box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #ccc, -2px 1px 10px #ccc, 0 -1px 10px #ccc;}}

body {
  background-color: #9fd8ee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div></div>
  <i style="left:50%;bottom:10%"></i>
  <i style="left:40%;bottom:30%"></i>
  <i style="left:60%;bottom:50%"></i>
  <i style="left:35%;bottom:60%"></i>
</div>
```

And here is many trees, enjoy!

```css
.tree {
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
  position:relative;
  /* the bottom of the tree */
  border-bottom:50px solid transparent;
  background:linear-gradient(maroon 0 0) bottom/20% 50px no-repeat border-box; 
}
.tree  div {
  padding-top:200%; /* keep it responsive at the same ratio */
}
.tree::before { /* the star */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 10%;
  left: 25%;    
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  background:yellow;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
}
.tree > div::before,
.tree > div::after{  /* the main part of the tree */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:25%;
  padding-right: 25%;
  --g:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,rgb(20, 97, 27) 50%) no-repeat;
  background:
    var(--g) -120% calc(0*100%/3),
    var(--g) -70%  calc(1*100%/3),
    var(--g) -30%  calc(2*100%/3),
    var(--g) 0     calc(3*100%/3);
  background-size:200% calc(100%/4 + var(--t,17%));
  background-origin: content-box;
} 
.tree > div::after {
  transform-origin:right;
  transform:scaleX(-1);
}
.tree::after { /* the non animated globes */
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
      /*                          color            position:  X   Y*/
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,red    98%,transparent ) 50% 30%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,blue   98%,transparent ) 60% 70%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,pink   98%,transparent ) 40% 50%,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,purple 98%,transparent ) 30% 90%;
  background-size:8% 4%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
i {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 4%;
  height: 2%;
  background: yellow;
  animation: ex 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes ex {
 50% {box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #ccc, -2px 1px 10px #ccc, 0 -1px 10px #ccc;}}

body {
  background-color: #9fd8ee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div></div>
  <i style="left:50%;bottom:10%"></i>
  <i style="left:40%;bottom:30%"></i>
  <i style="left:60%;bottom:50%"></i>
  <i style="left:35%;bottom:60%"></i>
</div>

<div class="tree" style="width:200px;--t:21%;">
  <div></div>
  <i style="left:50%;bottom:10%"></i>
  <i style="left:40%;bottom:20%"></i>
  <i style="left:60%;bottom:50%"></i>
  <i style="left:50%;bottom:60%"></i>
</div>

<div class="tree" style="width:150px;--t:14%;">
  <div></div>
</div>
```